# std::string insert a new string at specific location in stream

Tags: c++, string, iterator

I am trying to insert a new string in existing file dynamically. But currently I am using a constant number (specific index) for writing, but would like to avoid it as it might change in future. So instead of that I would like to get that to add at the end of the file but at a location which is fixed.

```
Hello <user_name>, please click **here** to proceed. //currently at position 33 link will be added
```

Here is what I tried:

```
std::stringstream buff;
std::fstream file(filepath, std::fstream::in)
for(std::string line; getline(file, line);)
{
   line.insert(33,/*link_val*/); //would like to avoid the magic number 33 and have something like from the end of line few positions before.
   buff << line;
}
file.close();
file.open(filepath, std::fstream::out);
file<<buff.str();
file.close();
```

Comment: `for(std::string line; getline();)` ? Before doing the next step you should make sure your current code is correct

Comment: *from the end of line few positions before*. Like `line.insert(line.size() - 2, /*link_val*/);` which is two positions before the end of the line.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number did not get the issue, could you pls point out the issue.

Comment: `getline()` does not compile, and if it would `line` is still an empty string.

Comment: got it! fixed the code now.

Comment: @highlander141 *//would like to avoid the magic number 33 and have something like from the end of line few positions before.* -- If this is the issue, where is the relevance of file reading/writing?  This is just a string manipulation issue, no?  What difference does it make where the `line` comes from?

Comment: are you asking how to find `**here**` in a string? Thats `std::string::find`